# Cacluate add vales while select defalut cheeck box& reduce values in adapter class

Tags: android

code in my project :
i want to Calculate adapterl Values show total price in text vew while click checkbow code:

```
Code:
    `int totalPrice = calculateTotalPrice();
     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
     (ch != null && ch.isChecked()) {
        if (isFirst)
       {
       totalPrice += calculateTotalPrice();
        }else {
       totalPrice -= calculateTotalPrice();
       
          }
          }
                                       
        total_price.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
                                   }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is a list of items with a isChecked boolean field and a getPrice() method, and total_price is your TextView

here is the code

```
int totalPrice = calculateTotalPrice();
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    YourDataClass item = data.get(i);
    if (item.isChecked()) {
        totalPrice += item.getPrice();
    } else {
        totalPrice -= item.getPrice();
    }
}
total_price.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
```

Comment: hi bro.But I Changed  YourDataclass  but error in the else part..

Comment: can you share adapter class code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private int totalValue = 0;
    boolean isChecked = true;
    static ArrayList<Product> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> data) {
        this.data = data;

    }

    @NonNull
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_product_adapter, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        Product product = data.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getProduct_Name());
        holder.quantity.setText(data.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.total.setText(data.get(position).getTotal());
        holder.ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            product.setChecked(isChecked);
            int productTotal = Integer.parseInt(product.getTotal());
            totalValue += isChecked ? productTotal : -productTotal; // Update total value
        });

        holder.ch.setChecked(product.isItemchecked());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView  name, quantity, price, total, total_price;
        CheckBox ch;

        @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Qty);
            total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_qty);
            total_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_price);
            ch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_checkbox);
        }

    }
}
```